# How can I make my site accessible by domain.com as well as www.domain.com without blocking Exchange email

Tags: domain-name-system, email, exchange

Right now my DNS settings look something like this:

```
| Host Name    | IP Address/URL                  | Record Type |
| ------------ | ------------------------------- | ----------- |
| www          | my.dns.com                      | CNAME       |
| autodiscover | autodiscover.outlook.com        | CNAME       |
| ftp          | my.dns.com                      | CNAME       |
| @            | v=spf1 include:outlook.com ~all | TXT Record  |
| @            | me.mail.eo.outlook.com          | MX          |
```

When I change them to look like this...

```
| Host Name    | IP Address/URL                  | Record Type |
| ------------ | ------------------------------- | ----------- |
| @            | mydns.com                       | CNAME       |
| www          | mydns.com                       | CNAME       |
| autodiscover | autodiscover.outlook.com        | CNAME       |
| ftp          | mydns.com                       | CNAME       |
| @            | v=spf1 include:outlook.com ~all | TXT Record  |
| @            | me.mail.eo.outlook.com          | MX          |
```

... my Exchange email stops working.

I want to be able to access my website at domain.com www.domain.com, and ftp.domain.com while still receiving email.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say you're e-mail stops working what does that mean? CNAME and A records should not have any affect on your MX record and the ability for the mail servers at Office 365 to route your messages.

Comment: When I add the  @|mydns.com|CNAME entry, I lose the ability to send messages, and messages sent to me never reach me.  Senders get a message undeliverable message a few days later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your record for mydns.com needs to be an 'A' record with an IP address and not a CNAME.

```
| Host Name    | IP Address/URL                  | Record Type |
| ------------ | ------------------------------- | ----------- |
| @            | mydns.com                       | A           |
```

Any 'MX' record must be attached to a corresponding 'A' record.

If you were to create "subdomain.mydns.com" it would need to be an 'A' record to attach an 'MX' record to it.  A 'CNAME' won't work.  Same goes for the naked domain.

You can get feedback on your public DNS configuration at http://intodns.com.  Just plug your domain in.  It will give you some suggestions.

Comment: Based on your answer, I was able to find the relevant support article on my hosting provider's site that says that CNAME entries for bare domain DNS entries won't work.  Thanks!